# Unable to export product CSV "No valid data sent"

Tags: magento-1.9, importexport, export

I am trying to export products using **System -> Import/Export -> Export** After selecting **Export Settings** and click on **Continue**, I am getting ***No valid data sent***.

Looking in the **system.log** It is showing:

> 2016-12-21T12:28:50+00:00 EMERG (0): Redis configuration does not exist, falling back to MySQL handler.
>
> 2016-12-21T12:28:50+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 4271  in /var/www/clients/client5618/web7022/web/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php on line 875

There are 7000+ products. Please let me know what is wrong with this and how do I fix it?

Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the error comes directly from the method **exportAction()** from **Mage_ImportExport_Adminhtml_ExportController** class:

```
public function exportAction()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->getPost(Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export::FILTER_ELEMENT_GROUP)) {
        try {
            /** @var $model Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export */
            $model = Mage::getModel('importexport/export');
            $model->setData($this->getRequest()->getParams());

            return $this->_prepareDownloadResponse(
                $model->getFileName(),
                $model->export(),
                $model->getContentType()
            );
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('No valid data sent'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('No valid data sent'));
    }
    return $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
}
```

So, check the **var/log/exception.log**, maybe you can see more information about the error.

Comment: Thank you @vishal_gelani ! I will check this and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue to this, however this above solution was not the cause.

I noticed in chrome debugger the following 500 error:

```
https://www.website.com.au/admin/export/getFilter/key/....../entity/catalog_product?isAjax=true
```

I installed a vanilla install of magento 2.1.8 and then reloaded the database.

From this I then took a look at product attributes. I know this was working recently, so some data change has made this come about.

So in summary, I removed the most recent product attributes I had created, and this resolved the issue.

One of the attributes added was causing the product filter screen to break down. Hence the blank page.

Anyway, hope this is useful

brendan